# Unity Survival Shooter Enemy taking no damage - Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to deploy the Unity Survival Shooter game to the android device. The game works just fine except when I shoot the enemy, it doesn't take any damage and don't die.
Here is my PlayerShooting script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace CompleteProject
{
public class PlayerShooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damagePerShot = 20;                  // The damage inflicted by each bullet.
    public float timeBetweenBullets = 0.15f;        // The time between each shot.
    public float range = 100f;                      // The distance the gun can fire.


    float timer;                                    // A timer to determine when to fire.
    Ray shootRay;                                   // A ray from the gun end forwards.
    RaycastHit shootHit;                            // A raycast hit to get information about what was hit.
    int shootableMask;                              // A layer mask so the raycast only hits things on the shootable layer.
    ParticleSystem gunParticles;                    // Reference to the particle system.
    LineRenderer gunLine;                           // Reference to the line renderer.
    AudioSource gunAudio;                           // Reference to the audio source.
    Light gunLight;                                 // Reference to the light component.
    public Light faceLight;                             // Duh
    float effectsDisplayTime = 0.2f;                // The proportion of the timeBetweenBullets that the effects will display for.
    public float timertime = 0.0f;


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Create a layer mask for the Shootable layer.
        shootableMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Shootable");

        // Set up the references.
        gunParticles = GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ();
        gunLine = GetComponent <LineRenderer> ();
        gunAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        gunLight = GetComponent<Light> ();
        //faceLight = GetComponentInChildren<Light> ();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

     #if !MOBILE_INPUT
        // If the Fire1 button is being press and it's time to fire...
        if(Input.GetButton ("Fire1") && timer >= timeBetweenBullets && Time.timeScale != 0)
        {
            // ... shoot the gun.
            Shoot ();
        }
       #else
        // If there is input on the shoot direction stick and it's time to fire.
        bool check = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("JumpButton");
        check = true;
        //Debug.Log(check);
        if(check == true)
       // if ((CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Move X") != 0 || CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Move Y") != 0) && timer >= timeBetweenBullets)
        {
            // ... shoot the gun
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            timertime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(timertime < 0.0f)
            {
                Shoot();
                timertime = 0.175f;
            }
        }
        #endif
        // If the timer has exceeded the proportion of timeBetweenBullets that the effects should be displayed for...
        if(timer >= timeBetweenBullets * effectsDisplayTime)
        {
            // ... disable the effects.
            DisableEffects ();
        }
    }


    public void DisableEffects ()
    {
        // Disable the line renderer and the light.
        gunLine.enabled = false;
        faceLight.enabled = false;
        gunLight.enabled = false;
    }


    public void Shoot ()
    {
        // Reset the timer.
        Debug.Log("Inside Shoot");
        timer = 0f;

        // Play the gun shot audioclip.
        gunAudio.Play ();

        // Enable the lights.
        gunLight.enabled = true;
        faceLight.enabled = true;

        // Stop the particles from playing if they were, then start the particles.
        gunParticles.Stop ();
        gunParticles.Play ();

        // Enable the line renderer and set it's first position to be the end of the gun.
        gunLine.enabled = true;
        gunLine.SetPosition (0, transform.position);

        // Set the shootRay so that it starts at the end of the gun and points forward from the barrel.
        shootRay.origin = transform.position;
        shootRay.direction = transform.forward;

        // Perform the raycast against gameobjects on the shootable layer and if it hits something...
        Debug.Log("Going inside Physics Raycast");
        if(Physics.Raycast (shootRay, out shootHit, range, shootableMask))
        {
            // Try and find an EnemyHealth script on the gameobject hit.
            Debug.Log("Inside Physics Raycast");
            EnemyHealth enemyHealth = shootHit.collider.GetComponent <EnemyHealth> ();
            Debug.Log (enemyHealth);
            Debug.Log ("Checking if enemyHealth is not null");

            // If the EnemyHealth component exist...
            if(enemyHealth != null)
            {
                // ... the enemy should take damage.
                Debug.Log("Inside enemyHealth != null if condition");
                enemyHealth.TakeDamage (damagePerShot, shootHit.point);
            }

            // Set the second position of the line renderer to the point the raycast hit.
            gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootHit.point);
        }
        // If the raycast didn't hit anything on the shootable layer...
        else
        {
            // ... set the second position of the line renderer to the fullest extent of the gun's range.
            gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootRay.origin + shootRay.direction * range);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is my EnemyHealth script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace CompleteProject
{
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startingHealth = 100;            // The amount of health the enemy starts the game with.
    public int currentHealth;                   // The current health the enemy has.
    public float sinkSpeed = 2.5f;              // The speed at which the enemy sinks through the floor when dead.
    public int scoreValue = 10;                 // The amount added to the player's score when the enemy dies.
    public AudioClip deathClip;                 // The sound to play when the enemy dies.


    Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator.
    AudioSource enemyAudio;                     // Reference to the audio source.
    ParticleSystem hitParticles;                // Reference to the particle system that plays when the enemy is damaged.
    CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;            // Reference to the capsule collider.
    bool isDead;                                // Whether the enemy is dead.
    bool isSinking;                             // Whether the enemy has started sinking through the floor.


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        enemyAudio = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
        hitParticles = GetComponentInChildren <ParticleSystem> ();
        capsuleCollider = GetComponent <CapsuleCollider> ();

        // Setting the current health when the enemy first spawns.
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // If the enemy should be sinking...
        if(isSinking)
        {
            // ... move the enemy down by the sinkSpeed per second.
            transform.Translate (-Vector3.up * sinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }


    public void TakeDamage (int amount, Vector3 hitPoint)
    {
        // If the enemy is dead...
        if(isDead)
            // ... no need to take damage so exit the function.
            return;

        // Play the hurt sound effect.
        enemyAudio.Play ();

        // Reduce the current health by the amount of damage sustained.
        currentHealth -= amount;

        // Set the position of the particle system to where the hit was sustained.
        hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint;

        // And play the particles.
        hitParticles.Play();

        // If the current health is less than or equal to zero...
        if(currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // ... the enemy is dead.
            Death ();
        }
    }


    void Death ()
    {
        // The enemy is dead.
        isDead = true;

        // Turn the collider into a trigger so shots can pass through it.
        capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;

        // Tell the animator that the enemy is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger ("Dead");

        // Change the audio clip of the audio source to the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt clip playing).
        enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
        enemyAudio.Play ();
    }


    public void StartSinking ()
    {
        // Find and disable the Nav Mesh Agent.
        GetComponent <UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent> ().enabled = false;

        // Find the rigidbody component and make it kinematic (since we use Translate to sink the enemy).
        GetComponent <Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = true;

        // The enemy should no sink.
        isSinking = true;

        // Increase the score by the enemy's score value.
        ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;

        // After 2 seconds destory the enemy.
        Destroy (gameObject, 2f);
    }
}
}
```

I have put the log everywhere and found that the enemyHealth object from PlayerShooting script is always returning Null even though if I hit the enemy with bullets.

[image: PlayerShooting script Screenshot]

[image: Unity Screenshot]

Need to know why it is always returning Null and how do I make it other than Null when I hit the enemy.

Comment: Do `Debug.Log(shootableMask)` and tell me what the value is

Comment: The value is 512. @Programmer

Comment: Did you try the answer I left?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using Layer to make sure that the raycast hit just the GameObjects on the shootableMask layer which is the "Shootable" layer so layer issue problem is eliminated.

The only possible problem left is that the `EnemyHealth` script is not attached to the GameObject or maybe some of the GameObjects.

Go through all your GameObjects and prefabs, select each one on the "Shootable" layer then *make sure that the `EnemyHealth` script is attached to them*. The `GetComponent <EnemyHealth>()` should never be `null` if the `EnemyHealth` script is attached to each one.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `Getcomponent<>` function into `FindObjectOfType` because `Getcomponent` only gets the component from that game object, in this situation the `EnemyHealth` Script doesn't exist in same object with `PlayerShooting` so you cant get the component. [Read more about `FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

Comment: Not a good idea because OP wants to apply damage to the particular object hit by the raycast not just some random GameObject. Getcomponent is right in this case.